# Unable to load javascript

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs, custom-template

I'm trying to load javascript file in `app/code/Anime/Shipping/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` which overrides the core file `Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html`. I can see that I'm able to override properly. PHP cannot be written in `.html` file so I must achieve few customizations through the use of jQuery, and javascript resources available in Magento.
My `shipping.html` file is:

```
<li id="shipping" class="checkout-shipping-address" data-bind="fadeVisible: visible()">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Address'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-shipping"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">
       Test text to confirm.
        <button type="button"
                data-bind="click: showFormPopUp, visible: !isNewAddressAdded()"
                class="action action-show-popup">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'New Address'"></span></button>
        <div id="opc-new-shipping-address" data-bind="visible: isFormPopUpVisible()">
        </div>
    </div>
</li>


<!--Shipping method template-->
<li id="opc-shipping_method"
    class="checkout-shipping-method"
    data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading"
    role="presentation">
    <div class="checkout-shipping-method">
        <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Methods'" data-role="title"></div>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-shipping-method-form') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <div id="checkout-step-shipping_method"
             class="step-content"
             data-role="content"
             role="tabpanel"
             aria-hidden="false">
            <!-- ko if: rates().length  -->
            <form class="form methods-shipping" id="co-shipping-method-form" data-bind="submit: setShippingInformation" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
                    <table class="table-checkout-shipping-method">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="row">
                                <th class="col col-method" data-bind="i18n: 'Select Method'"></th>
                                <th class="col col-price" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></th>
                                <th class="col col-method" data-bind="i18n: 'Method Title'"></th>
                                <th class="col col-carrier" data-bind="i18n: 'Carrier Title'"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        <!--ko foreach: { data: rates(), as: 'method'}-->
                        <tr class="row" data-bind="click: $parent.selectShippingMethod">
                            <td class="col col-method">
                                <!-- ko ifnot: method.error_message -->
                                <!-- ko if: $parent.rates().length == 1 -->
                                <input class="radio"
                                       type="radio"
                                       data-bind="attr: {
                                                    checked: $parent.rates().length == 1,
                                                    'value' : method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                                                    'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code,
                                                    'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code
                                                 }" />
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!--ko ifnot: ($parent.rates().length == 1)-->
                                <input type="radio"
                                       data-bind="
                                                value: method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                                                checked: $parent.isSelected,
                                                attr: {
                                                    'id': 's_method_' + method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                                                    'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code
                                                },
                                                click: $parent.selectShippingMethod"
                                       class="radio"/>
                                <!--/ko-->
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </td>
                            <td class="col col-price">
                                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('price') -->
                                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </td>

                            <td class="col col-method"
                                    data-bind="text: method.method_title, attr: {'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>

                            <td class="col col-carrier"
                                    data-bind="text: method.carrier_title, attr: {'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- ko if:  method.error_message -->
                        <tr class="row row-error">
                            <td class="col col-error" colspan="4">
                                <div class="message error">
                                    <div data-bind="text: method.error_message"></div>
                                </div>
                                <span class="no-display">
                                    <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: {'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code}"/>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- /ko -->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
                    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shippingAdditional') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <!-- ko if: errorValidationMessage().length > 0 -->
                <div class="message notice">
                    <span><!-- ko text: errorValidationMessage()--><!-- /ko --></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
                    <div class="primary">
                        <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: rates().length > 0 --><div class="no-quotes-block"><!-- ko i18n: 'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time'--><!-- /ko --></div><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

My require js file is:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html':
                'Anime_Shipping/template/shipping.html'
        }
    },
    mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                'Anime_Shipping/js/shipping': true
            }
        }
};
```

Neither alert is seen nor log in console. What might be the reason? Or is there another way of loading js in this kind of template file?

Comment: Clear the cache and static content folders, and run the deploy command.

Comment: Not working after doing so.

Answer (score 2):

To load your custom javascript within shipping you need to extend

> Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping.js

You can either override this js into your theme package by copying the above file into the following place and add your custom function.

> /app/design/frontend/vendor/themePackage/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js

or extend using mixins. To know how to extend using mixins see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html

For example add in your requirejs-config.js,

```
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order': {
                'Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/model/place-order-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and **app/code/Magento/CheckoutAgreements/view/frontend/web/js/model/place-order-mixin.js**

```
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/model/agreements-assigner'
], function ($, wrapper, agreementsAssigner) {
    'use strict';

    return function (placeOrderAction) {

        /** Override default place order action and add agreement_ids to request */
        return wrapper.wrap(placeOrderAction, function (originalAction, paymentData, messageContainer) {
            agreementsAssigner(paymentData);

            return originalAction(paymentData, messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: HOw to override through module, I have not created theme.

Comment: Then you need to use mixins.

Comment: can you show me in the answer. I'm trying but no luck.

Comment: please check my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I could not understand mixins, suggested by @Salma Saiyad, anyway thanks to you. So I had to search for another approach to load js file. I had to modify my requirejs file as below:

```
var config = {
    map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping':'Anime_CategoryTree/js/shipping',
        'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html': 
                'Anime_CategoryTree/template/shipping.html' 
        }
    }
};
```

On doing so I could override shipping.html and shipping.js with mapping. But had to copy whole shipping.js from core to my module. It worked and could perform my customizations.